# on redirecting to a previous html page the page should not refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

Actually I have two fields in "click.html".One is "Name" field and other is "client_ip" field.I have entered my name in the "Name" field and later on click of "client_ip" text box has redirected to index.html.

In index.html I'll select some required client_ip's and redirect the page again to click.html.So that the selected client_ip fields are placed in the client_ip text box of click.html page.

Now after redirecting to the click.html,the name I had entered in the "Name" text box is vanishing because of page refresh while redirecting.But Now,I want to redirect to click.html without refreshing the click.html page.How can I achieve this ...

My click.html:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpryvkin/Plugins/master/pagination/simple_numbers_no_ellipses.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <label>Start Time:<select id="Start Time" id="startID" name="StartTime">        
            <option value="00:00" >00:00</option>
            <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
            <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
            <option value="01:30">01:30</option>
            <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
            <option value="02:30">02:30</option>
            <option vlaue="03:00">03:00</option>

        </select></label>
</div>
<div id="clicDiv">
Client IP :<input type="text" id="ipClick"  onclick="getValue();" name="Client IP" style="width:600px;"/>
</div>
<script>

function getUSERIP(){

if(!window.location.href.match(/client_ip=.*?([^\&]+)/))
   return;
var ip = window.location.href.match(/client_ip=.*?([^\&]+)/)[0].replace('client_ip=','');
var res = ip.replace(/%2C/g,",")
$("#ipClick").val(res);

}
getUSERIP();

function getUSERName(){

if(!window.location.href.match(/name=.*?([^\&]+)/))
   return;
var name = window.location.href.match(/name=.*?([^\&]+)/)[0].replace('name=','');

if($("#hiddenName").length)
  $("#hiddenName").val(name);
else $('#textDiv').val(name);

}
getUSERName();

function getStartTime(){

if(!window.location.href.match(/StartTime=.*?([^\&]+)/))
   return;
var StartTime = window.location.href.match(/StartTime=.*?([^\&]+)/)[0].replace('StartTime=','');
var res = StartTime.replace(/%253A/g,",")
if($("#hiddenName5").length)
  $("#hiddenName5").val(res);
else $('#startID').val(res);

}
getStartTime();


function getValue(){
var name = $("#textDiv").val()?('?name='+$("#textDiv").val()):'';
location.href='/home/divya/html_docs/index.html'+name;

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpryvkin/Plugins/master/pagination/simple_numbers_no_ellipses.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">


  <script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

$("#ip").val('');

    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "pagingType": "full_numbers"
    } );
} );

</script>

  </head>
  <body>

<div>
<form action="/home/divya/html_docs/click.html" method="get" >
Client_ip :<input type="text" id ="ip" name="client_ip" style="width: 600px;"/>
<div id="subDiv">
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</div></br>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
</table>

   <script>
  var selectedIps = [];
  var tabulate = function (data,columns) {
var svg = d3.select('#ip').append("svg")
  var table = d3.select('#example')
    var thead = table.append('thead')
    var tbody = table.append('tbody')

    thead.append('tr')
      .selectAll('th')
        .data(columns)
        .enter()
      .append('th')
        .text(function (d) { return d })

    var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
      .append('tr')

    var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
        .data(function(row) {
            return columns.map(function (column) {
                return { column: column, value: row[column] }
          })
      })
      .enter()
    .append('td')
   .text(function (d) { return d.value })
   .append("input")
   .attr("id","change")
   .attr("type", "checkbox")
   .style("float","left")
.on("change", function(d, i) {
            if ($(this)[0].checked) {
              if (selectedIps.indexOf(d.value) < 0) {
                selectedIps.push(d.value);
              }
            } else {
              if (selectedIps.indexOf(d.value) > -1) {
                selectedIps.splice(selectedIps.indexOf(d.value), 1);
              }
            }
            $('#ip').val(selectedIps.join(','));
          });


  return table;
}

d3.csv('some1.csv',function (data) {
    var columns = ['client_ip']
  tabulate(data,columns)
});
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please help me out...

Comment: an easy but not perfect way could be setting session variables with the values you want to persist , and on the page load load those values into felds, or having some back system with clases to save those values.

Comment: Are you able to use php at all? PHP is a serverside programming language which can handle forms much easier than javascript can alone

Comment: How can we set the session variables here ?

Comment: No,I'm not using PHP at all.

Comment: Are you able to add the name variable to the url like you are with the client_ip?

Comment: No,I'm not sending name variable to any url.Just I'll enter the name in click.html .But I want to persist the  entered name after redirection from index.html also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update function on click.html

```
function getValue(){
var name = $("#textDiv").val()?('?name='+$("#textDiv").val()):'';
location.href='/home/divya/html_docs/index.html'+name;

}
```

on index.html

Put hidden in form element

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenName" name="name" />
```

Put this function on common js file or in both index.html and click.html

```
function getUSERName(){

if(!window.location.href.match(/name=.*?([^\&]+)/))
   return;
var name = window.location.href.match(/name=.*?([^\&]+)/)[0].replace('name=','');

if($("#hiddenName").length)
  $("#hiddenName").val(name);
else $('#textDiv').val(name);

}
getUSERName();
```

Comment: In this part,I'm facing issue....  if($("#hiddenName5").length)
  $("#hiddenName5").val(res);
else $('#startID').val(res);

Comment: check this may be it's help you **StartTime = StartTime.replace(/\%253A/g,",")**

Comment: var res = StartTime.replace(/%253A/g,":").Actually through this I'm able to get the correct value like this "02:00" as start time.But unable to place it in the drop down box of start time

Comment: there is typo **<select id="Start Time" id="startID" name="StartTime">** you mention two ids and spell of value **<option vlaue="05:30">05:30</option>** please update this

Comment: You can't change spell of value in options and id should be startTime (not start time) update this.

Comment: Finally I got it.Now,the code is working fine.Thanks a lot for ur patience

Comment: Congrat's finally you did it. (i'm joking)